# ngTagsInput not working in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I've test the ngTagsInput and i've set it up properly, however the ngTagsinput module doesn't work in ng-repeat, is there a wokaround for this? Thank you.
https://jsfiddle.net/wmsoor18/
Sample code;

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{tags}}
    <div ng-repeat="sub in ['sub1','sub2']">
        <tags-input ng-model="tags[sub]"></tags-input>
    </div>
<div>

angular
.module('myApp', ['ngTagsInput'])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    //$scope.tags = {};
});
```

This one is working without ng-repeat;
http://jsfiddle.net/r78ohcf0/1/

Answer (score 0):

`ngTagsInput` directive takes an array of tag objects. You don't need to iterate through the array of tag objects. `ngTagsInput` does it for you.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pahan_silva/0sbqgfhh/4/)

Comment: Thank you, but how can i use it under ng-repeat?

Comment: ngTagsInput directive does the work for you. Why do you want to use `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: i need one of my fields to have a tags under the loop using ng-repeat

Comment: What do you mean by fields?

Comment: let's say i have tags directive inside ng-repeat so it will loop to get all the data. i want to have tags directive that comes out of the loop to have ngTagsInput

Comment: I'm not sure what your need is. Can you edit the question with more clear details.

Comment: how can you make ngTagsInput work inside ng-repeat? jsfiddle.net/wmsoor18